# How to unpack msgpack record

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack, msgpack, servicestack.redis

I am using Redis and C#. I saved my user data in Redis with msgPack format. How can I deserialize msgPack data? I guess, some records are different from the current user model in Redis. I usually get the serialize exceptions when I try to deserialize it. I need to see these records. is there any way for that?

```
 var serializedValue = redisClient.Get(value.Key);
 if (serializedValue != null)
     value.Value = serializedValue.FromMsgPack<T>();
```

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The unpacked value is not 'System.Int16' type. Do not convert System.Boolean (binary:0x0) MessagePackObject to System.Int16.
   at ServiceStack.MsgPack.MsgPackFormat.HandleException(Exception ex, Type type)
   at ServiceStack.MsgPack.MsgPackFormat.Deserialize(Type type, Stream fromStream)
   at ServiceStack.MsgPack.MsgPackExtensions.FromMsgPack[T](Byte[] bytes)
```